# iframe overflowing it's container

Tags: reactjs, iframe, responsive-design, tailwind-css, overflow

I'm trying to create a layout similar to this one by Wistia https://home.wistia.com/live/events/pnd98h7ffa?utm_campaign=2023%20Webinar%20Series&utm_medium=email&_hsmi=265945727&_hsenc=p2ANqtz--pQsHAbm-wIrzjy0fSLCgy63Z71DSHLtAlykHKCOOrVLGZQBflaCGBpRg2kCj9P55DoC0YrSAsCMIkc_7qJ0XAVNkLhA&utm_content=265945727&utm_source=hs_email all you have to do is to subscribe using any credentials : [image]

I'm using react and tailwind for this but I'm having a problem where the iframe overflows it's container for large screen.
This is a pseudo code that reproduces the same bug

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 10vh;
  background: crimson;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content iframe {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  border: 0;
}

.content div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content">
      <iframe title="test" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7PIji8OubXU?si=XmbTvMWI5rlwS1ix"></iframe>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </main>

</body>
```

this is a picture of the bug: [image]

I tried setting a max-height: 100% for the iframe it stopped overflowing in height but the width kept increasing even when I've tried to set the max-width:100%; when i tried to set a fixed max-width:500px for example the width stopped increasing but the iframe is no longer responsive and black blocks/Lines started to appear on the sides of it. Idk what's the problem causing this behavior and it's frustrating. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is beause you're setting the `width` and then the `aspect-ratio` upsets that. If you set the `height: 100%;` (instead of `width`) then I believe that should work; see the snippet below:

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 10vh;
  background: crimson;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content iframe {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  border: 0;
}

.content div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content">
      <iframe title="test" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7PIji8OubXU?si=XmbTvMWI5rlwS1ix"></iframe>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </main>

</body>
```

As per your comments, I think at the point where these is an issue on smaller devices, yes, you want to consider the `@media` queries. And/or using `flex-wrap: wrap;` compare these next two snippets.

Two things I've added to each of these next snippets:

- a [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) value on each of the `div` and `iframe`

  - this will allow them to grow and shrink at different rates (which you may find beneficial)
- coupled with a `min-width` for the `div` element so that the `iframe` isn't hogging all the screen space

This second snippet doesn't have `flex-wrap: wrap;` and will overflow when the screen is too small for both elements side-by-side:

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 10vh;
  background: crimson;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content iframe {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  border: 0;
  flex: 2 1;
}

.content div {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background: dodgerblue;
  flex: 1 2;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content">
      <iframe title="test" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7PIji8OubXU?si=XmbTvMWI5rlwS1ix"></iframe>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </main>

</body>
```

This has `flex-wrap: wrap` and the above points and will wrap when the style feels it has no other choice:

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 10vh;
  background: crimson;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content iframe {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  border: 0;
  flex: 2 1;
}

.content div {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  background: dodgerblue;
  flex: 1 2;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content">
      <iframe title="test" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7PIji8OubXU?si=XmbTvMWI5rlwS1ix"></iframe>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </main>

</body>
```

Perhaps `max-width: 100%;` would also address your concern since it doesn't actively apply itself to the width of the `iframe` but will take over when the screens are *very* small.

I wouldn't worry about screens narrower than 320px, many companies/developers/blogs say this too:

- [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/screen-sizes-and-breakpoints-for-responsive-design#breakpoints)
- [UX Pickle](https://uxpickle.com/what-is-the-smallest-screen-size-you-should-design-for/)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! i used your code and it did work for larger screens but on the other hand it didn't work for smaller screen as the iframe didn't shrink and kept it's size as the screen went smaller, so i tried to add a max-width:100% and it kind of worked at first but for some smaller dimension the sidebar disappears and the iframe gets the full width and height of the container then I get those "black" bars on the vertical sides for the iframe. Should I just use media queries and handle it for smaller screens or there is something i'm missing?

Comment: I've added some more snippets discussing this (I think)